# Answers on pages 2 and later are not indexed by Google

Tags: bug, status-declined, search

I thought I'd note a somewhat poorly known feature of the Stack Exchange software we're using: when a question has more than 30 answers, so that they're spread over multiple pages, the second and later pages will have a [rel="canonical" link](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) pointing to the first page.

This means that **only the first page will be indexed by Google.**

For example, if you [search on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22com.aschroder.christmastree%22) for [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4144), currently at score -1 and page 2, the only result you'll get is [a mirror site](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=codegolf.stackexchange&question=4114&printer=false&linktohome=true).  (Yes, I know that's not an answer anyone is likely to search for, but I picked it for the example since it has a low score and contains a distinctive string.)

I recently started [a thread about this on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130749/improper-use-of-rel-canonical-is-hurting-search).  Since I mentioned codegolf.SE as an example of a site affected by this feature/bug, I thought I'd post a note about it here as well.  Those interested in commenting on the issue in general, as opposed to merely in the scope of this site, should head over there.

I do feel it would be good for codegolf.SE to have this feature disabled here, even if it ends up being kept enabled for other SE sites.

---

**Update:** The MSO proposal has been marked as declined.  Still, one can at least hope that we might be able to get this feature disabled (and, ideally, replaced with proper [rel="next" / "prev" links](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663744)) locally here on codegolf.SE.

We could perhaps even serve as a testbed for this, to see if there really is anything to some of the more extreme "*OMG Google will punish us for showing the question text on multiple pages!*" fears voiced on the MSO thread.  We've got a *lot* of multi-page threads here (compared to most SE sites), so if our Google ranking won't crash and burn as a result of this, neither should anyone else's.